# Line break on javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I have tried a lot to add line break but it dose not work... replace \n with line brack
I'm going to save html form in txt format in Notepad see all input text with one line which is i don't want that...

need your help please.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--


function buildData(){
var txtData = "00"+$("#nameField").val()+
        "  "+$("#title").val()+
        "0000000000"+$("#lastNameField").val()+
        "\r\n Gender: "+($("#genderMale").is(":checked")?"Male":"Female");

return txtData;
}
// This will be executed when the document is ready
$(function(){
// This will act when the submit BUTTON is clicked
$("#formToSave").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var txtData = buildData();
    window.location.href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,"+Base64.encode(txtData);
});

// This will act when the submit LINK is clicked
$("#submitLink").click(function(event){
    var txtData = buildData();
    $(this).attr('download','sugguestedName.txt')
        .attr('href',"data:application/octet-stream;base64,"+Base64.encode(txtData));
});
});
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" id="formToSave">
<dl>
    <dt>Date:</dt>
    <dd>
    <input type="text" id="nameField" value="00002014" />
    <input type="text" id="title" value="Credit Card Payment" />
    </dd>
    <dt>Card No:</dt>
    <dd><input type="text" id="lastNameField" value="Last Name" /></dd>
    <dt>Gender:</dt>
    <dd><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="gender" value="M" id="genderMale" />
        Male
        <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="gender" value="F" />
        Female
</dl>
<p><a href="javascript://Save as TXT" id="submitLink">Save as TXT</a></p>
<p><button type="submit"><img src="http://www.suttonrunners.org/images/save_icon.gif" alt=""/> Save as TXT</button></p>
```

thank in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is not in Javascript, but in the way it is shown afterwards. Try `alert(buildData())`, does it work properly? If you're appending the text to the DOM, you have to use HTML line feeds, like `<br>`.

Comment: thanks for your replay. actually i want save data in txt format..it save it all in one line.

Comment: You might try "\r\n" instead of only "\n" because windows needs that. Oh I see you already tried that. Can you upload an example txt file somewhere? Because that looks weired

Comment: Actually, your code works for me when I use [btoa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript) instead of your Base64 library.

Comment: this is notepad file look like:  0000002014KIB  Credit Card Payment
0000000000Last Name
 Gender: Female

Comment: let me try btoa please

Comment: btoa is library? i can not find it..can you send me a link please

Comment: btoa is only available in IE10+ and any recent sane browser.

Answer (score 0):

Tried running the above mentioned after removing the jQuery added in. It did work as expected.

1. Please make sure that the returned string "txtData"  is properly concatenated.
2. If properly concatenated then it should work unless being appended to DOM in which case you have to use a 
    tag

Comment: thanks Raviteja Avvari for your replay. actually i want save data in txt format..